# Silverlight based Wiki Software

Tags: .net, silverlight, wiki

Does anybody know if there is a **Silverlight based (free / opensource) Wiki Software**?
In other words I am looking for some reasons for a Wiki like **ScreeTurnWiki** or **OpenWiki** which is based on Silverlight and not on ASP.NET.

Comment: Why would you want this?  I don't think Silverlight (although certainly more than capable) is very well suited to this type of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Silverlight isn't really good (nor designed for) text layout. It's a little better with the RichTextControl, but the technology remains quite limited (compared to basic HTML.) It's not suited for flow layout, and limits you to readonly RichTextControl for text display if you want copy & paste.

It would be possible to build a wiki with SL, but I don't see why you would do this. What do you want to add to your wiki which couldn't be enabled easily with HTML? (Out Of Browser perhaps?)

Moreover, using Silverlight will force you to expose your contents as HTML too for the search engines bots.

That makes as a whole a lot of issues, for what I feel is little reward.

Comment: Just a note... Text flow has improved with Silverlight 5 and the RickTextBoxOverflow controls

Comment: Yes, but even if these improvements are welcome, the Text flow system on SL5 is far from being as powerful as HTML. I guess that nothing can do well everything. ;)